# Do connected complete metric spaces always contain a path?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Does every connected complete metric space with more than one point contain a non-trivial path?  The pseudo-arc is an example of a connected metrizable space without a path.

Comment: This may be a bit extreme, but if you can work through the proof that the pseudoarc does not contain a nontrivial path, see if the lack of completeness is necessary.  If not, then just take the completion of the pseudoarc for your example.

Answer (score 2):

Such spaces do exist, since there are connected Polish spaces without non degenerate connected compact subsets. See the 1st answer to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/25171/how-thinly-connected-can-a-closed-subset-of-hilbert-space-be.

Comment: Yes. But not all Polish spaces are complete.

Comment: That's irrelevant.  By definition, each Polish space is completely metrizable.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks